# Spring boot Hibernate @OneToOne

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

Pretendo crear una relación `One To One` entre un usuario y su imagen de perfil subida directamente a la base de datos.
Estas son mis clases:

```
package org.tfg.teafind.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.tfg.teafind.utils.FileNameUtils;

@Entity
public class Imagen {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Lob
    private byte[] imagen;
    
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Usuario usuario;
    

    //Constructores, Getters y Setters
}
```

```
package org.tfg.teafind.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Entity
public class Usuario {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String nick;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido1;
    private String apellido2;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String telefono;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    
    private String password;
    private String descripcion;
    
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Imagen fotoPerfil;
    
    private boolean admin;
    
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Habilidad> sabe;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "leader")
    private Collection<Proyecto> creados;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ocupante")
    private Collection<Puesto> ocupa;
    
    
    //Constructores, Getters y Setters
}
```

En el anterior caso, no tengo problemas en subir las imágenes a la `BBDD`, pero la columna `imagen_id` en la tabla de `Usuario` se queda a `NULL`

He probado con las notaciones que podéis ver y con otras opciones como:

```
public class Usuario {

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="usuario")
  private Imagen imagen;
}
```

```
public class Imagen {
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="imagen_id")
  private Usuario usuario;
}
```

Pero en casos diferentes al que tengo ahora me da errores al compilar o al subir la imagen a la base de datos.

Edito:
Sigo probando opciones y algo me estoy dejando, porque sigo igual. Me sube bien las imágenes al `LONGBLOB` de *MySQL*, y en la tabla de usuario me sale la columna imagen_id, pero no me aparece el id. Y si lo pongo yo manualmente si que me dirige a la imágen, por lo que la relación es como que está medio hecha, pero no me la termina de crear...

```
public class Usuario {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "imagen_id", nullable = true)
    private Imagen imagen;
}
```

```
public class Imagen {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "imagen")
    private Usuario usuario;
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probar añadiendo al @JoinColumn(name = "imagen_id", nullable = true, unique = true) para indicar que la columna de la FK es única sin diferente resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Era un error muy tonto que no estaba contemplando por haberlo hecho y haberlo machacado al descartar mis cambios en el controlador en pro del controlador de mi repositorio. Simplemente no estaba haciendo el usuario.setImagen, por eso no me vinculaba el id de la imagen ya en la base de datos. Lo dejo por aquí por si a alguien le pasa algo parecido pueda consultarlo.